# Utilizando sfml c++

Tags: c++

Estoy programando un juego llamado el molino con la libreria sfml en dev.
Tengo una clase juego que es donde proceso la creacion de la venta, el fondo y la ventana,
tengo un vector de

```
class Juego{
        private:
            RenderWindow *ventana;
            Event *event; 
            Vector2i posicionMouse;
            Texture *fondo;
            Texture *mapa;
            Sprite *sprFondo;
            Sprite *sprMapa;
            int fps;
            Sprite sprFichita[24];

        public:
            Juego(Vector2i dimension, char * titulo);
            void Dibujar();
            void gameLoop();
            void Procesar_Eventos();
            void  setPosM();
    };  



Juego::Juego(){
ventana = new RenderWindow(VideoMode (dimension.x,dimension.y),titulo);
    ventana->setFramerateLimit(fps);
    event = new Event;  
    fondo = new Texture;
    mapa = new Texture;
    fondo->loadFromFile("img/fondo.png");
    sprFondo = new Sprite;
    sprFondo->setTexture(*fondo);
    sprFondo->setScale((float)ventana ->getSize().x/ sprFondo->getTexture()->getSize().x,(float)ventana->getSize().y /sprFondo->getTexture()->getSize().y);

    mapa->loadFromFile("img/mapita.png");
    sprMapa = new Sprite;
```

//agregando la textura al sprite de Mapa
        sprMapa->setTexture(*mapa);

```
    sprMapa->setPosition(400,300);
```

//posicionando la imagen en el centro de la ventana

```
sprMapa->setOrigin(sprMapa->getTexture()->getSize().x/2.f,sprMapa->getTexture()->getSize().y/2.f);
  fichita = new Texture;
    for(int i = 0;i<24; i++){
                ventana->draw(sprFichita[i]);
        }
}

///`Procesador de eventos`
void Juego::Procesar_Mouse(){

    posicion = Mouse::getPosition(*ventana);
    posicion = (Vector2i)ventana->mapPixelToCoords(posicion);
}
//Proceador deteccion de mouse sobre el sprite
void Juego::Procesar_Colisiones(){
    FloatRect posicion_del_mouse(Vector2f(posicion),{32,32});

    if(sprFichita[0]->getGlobalBounds().intersects(posicion_del_mouse)){
            sprFichita[0]->setColor(Color::Blue);
            std::cout<<"Entro\n";
    }else{
        sprFichita[0]->setColor(Color::Red);
        std::cout<<"Salio\n";

}
```

Esto funciona para un sprite en especifico pero quiero hacerlo para todos los sprites pero no se como hacerlo, puede hacerlos todos uno por uno pero me parece que es muy tedioso

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: osea ahi en el codigo cuando detecto la colisión lo hago con el vector de sprites en la posicion 0, pero quiero poder hacerlo para todos al mismo tiempo pues, pero no se como tienes al guna idea

Comment: ¿La pregunta es sobre colisiones entre sprites?

Comment: si men, entre sprites y el mouse

Comment: Entonces puedes reducir el código. Por favor comparte sólo la parte relevante.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Juego::Procesar_Colisiones(){
    FloatRect posicion_del_mouse(Vector2f(posicion),{32,32});

    if(sprFichita[0]->getGlobalBounds().intersects(posicion_del_mouse)){
            sprFichita[0]->setColor(Color::Blue);
            std::cout<<"Entro\n";
    }else{
        sprFichita[0]->setColor(Color::Red);
        std::cout<<"Salio\n";

}
```

o sea en vez de colocar posicion por posicion del vector como haria para que me detecte todo de una sola vez?